# Will re-configuring PHP erase the previous configure commands?

Tags: php

I have PHP installed on a machine, and running phpinfo() shows a lot of commands that were issued when PHP was first configured:

```
'./configure' '--prefix=/usr/local/zend' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/zend/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/zend/etc/conf.d' '--disable-debug' '--enable-inline-optimization' '--disable-all' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-session' '--enable-spl' '--enable-xml' '--enable-hash' '--enable-reflection' '--with-pear' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/zend/apache2/bin/apxs' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-filter' '--with-pcre-regex' '--with-zlib=/usr/local/zlib-1.2.3' '--enable-simplexml' '--enable-dom' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr/local/libxml-2.7.7' '--with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl-0.9.8o' '--enable-pdo' '--with-pdo-sqlite' '--with-readline=/usr/local/readline-5.2' '--with-iconv' '--with-sqlite3' '--disable-phar'
```

My application has evolved though, and I now need to connect to SQL Server from my linux machine. According to [php's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php), I need to configure PHP with the following command:

```
./configure --with-pdo-odbc=generic,/usr/local,libname,ldflags,cflags
```

I have two questions:

1. When I configure php with the new command, do I need to specify all of the previous commands as well (or will they be lost if I don't)?
2. Where do I run the `configure` command from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you will lose all of the previous commands. If you don't want to lose them, just copy the configure string and add your new options into it.

   `'./configure' '--prefix=/usr/local/zend' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/zend/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/zend/etc/conf.d' '--disable-debug' '--enable-inline-optimization' '--disable-all' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-session' '--enable-spl' '--enable-xml' '--enable-hash' '--enable-reflection' '--with-pear' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/zend/apache2/bin/apxs' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-filter' '--with-pcre-regex' '--with-zlib=/usr/local/zlib-1.2.3' '--enable-simplexml' '--enable-dom' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr/local/libxml-2.7.7' '--with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl-0.9.8o' '--enable-pdo' '--with-pdo-sqlite' '--with-readline=/usr/local/readline-5.2' '--with-iconv' '--with-sqlite3' '--disable-phar' '--with-pdo-odbc=generic,/usr/local,libname,ldflags,cflags'`
2. It needs to be run on the command line in a shell prompt. If you do not have shell access, you'll need to contact your host.